# How to make circle always touched only the edge with one another?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make three circles touched to each other. So far I am able to make to touch with each other. How do I make the other one touched with others when the radius of the circle is dynamic?

I was planning on use position absolute but I am not sure how this would behave on the dynamic radius.

Is there a way to do this? Any help or suggestion is appreciated.
[image: Something like this.]

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-night-qnyt8?file=/index.html)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <style>
      .circle-diagram {
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 190px;
      }
      .circle-diagram .solar-grid-wrapper {
        display: flex;
      }
      .circle-diagram .yellow-circle,
      .circle-diagram .yellow-circle-shadow {
        border-radius: 50%;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 12px;
        width: 130px;
        height: 130px;
        background-color: #feda02;
      }
      .circle-diagram .green-circle,
      .circle-diagram .green-circle-shadow {
        border-radius: 50%;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 12px;
        width: 91.05px;
        height: 91.05px;
        background-color: #25dc8a;
        left: 124px;
        top: 15px;
      }
      .circle-diagram .blue-circle,
      .circle-diagram .blue-circle-shadow {
        border-radius: 50%;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 12px;
        width: 119.8px;
        height: 119.8px;
        background: #3d7ff9;
        left: 108px;
        top: 106px;
      }
      .circle-diagram .symbol {
        height: 15px;
        margin-bottom: 8px;
      }
      .circle-diagram .value {
        z-index: 10;
        opacity: 1;
        font-weight: 550;
      }

      #randomButton {
        margin-top: 60px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        background: #3d7ff9;
        padding: 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="circle-diagram">
      <div class="solar-grid-wrapper">
        <div
          class="yellow-circle"
          id="circle1"
          style="width: 150px; height: 150px;"
        >
          <div class="value">Cool text 1</div>
        </div>
        <div
          class="blue-circle"
          id="circle2"
          style="width: 160px; height: 160px;"
        >
          <div class="value">Cool text 2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div
        class="green-circle"
        id="circle3"
        style="width: 222px; height: 222px;"
      >
        <div class="value">Cool text 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button id="randomButton">Random Width</button>
  </body>
  <script>
    document.getElementById("randomButton").addEventListener(
      "click",
      function() {
        function random(min, max) {
          return Math.round(Math.random() * Math.abs(max - min) + min);
        }
        const randomNumber1 = random(150, 220);
        const randomNumber2 = random(150, 220);
        const randomNumber3 = random(150, 220);
        document.getElementById("circle1").style.width = `${randomNumber1}px`;
        document.getElementById("circle1").style.height = `${randomNumber1}px`;
        document.getElementById("circle2").style.width = `${randomNumber2}px`;
        document.getElementById("circle2").style.height = `${randomNumber2}px`;
        document.getElementById("circle3").style.width = `${randomNumber3}px`;
        document.getElementById("circle3").style.height = `${randomNumber3}px`;
      },
      false
    );
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.getElementById("randomButton").addEventListener(
  "click",
  function() {
    function random(min, max) {
      return Math.round(Math.random() * Math.abs(max - min) + min);
    }
    const r1 = random(150, 220);
    const r2 = random(150, 220);
    const r3 = random(150, 220);
    var circle1 = document.getElementById("circle1"),
      circle2 = document.getElementById("circle2"),
      circle3 = document.getElementById("circle3");
   
    var h =(r1>r2)? Math.sqrt((r1/2+r3/2)*(r1/2+r3/2)-r1*r1/4):Math.sqrt((r2/2+r3/2)*(r2/2+r3/2)-r2*r2/4),
    h2 = (r1>r2)? (r1+r3)/2:(r2+r3)/2,
    alpha = (r1>r2)?r1/r2:r2/r1;
    
    circle3.style.left =`${alpha*(h-h2)}px`;
    circle3.style.top =`${(5/4)*alpha*(r1-r2)/2}px`;
    
    circle1.style.width = `${r1}px`;
    circle1.style.height = `${r1}px`;
    circle2.style.width = `${r2}px`;
    circle2.style.height = `${r2}px`;
    circle3.style.width = `${r3}px`;
    circle3.style.height = `${r3}px`;
  },
  false
);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.circle-diagram {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
 
}

.circle-diagram .solar-grid-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: gray;
}

.circle-diagram .yellow-circle,
.circle-diagram .yellow-circle-shadow {
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  background-color: #feda02;
  position: relative;
}

.circle-diagram .green-circle,
.circle-diagram .green-circle-shadow {
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: #25dc8a;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}

.circle-diagram .blue-circle,
.circle-diagram .blue-circle-shadow {
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 119.8px;
  height: 119.8px;
  background: #3d7ff9;
  position: relative;
}

.circle-diagram .symbol {
  height: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.circle-diagram .value {
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: 1;
  font-weight: 550;
}

#randomButton {
  margin-top: 60px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #3d7ff9;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Static Template</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="circle-diagram">
    <div class="solar-grid-wrapper">
      <div class="yellow-circle" id="circle1" style="width: 160px; height: 160px;">
        <div class="value">Cool text 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="blue-circle" id="circle2" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;">
        <div class="value">Cool text 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="green-circle" id="circle3" style="width: 222px; height: 222px;top:7.5Px;left:-18px;">
      <div class="value">Cool text 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button id="randomButton">Random Width</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Right now its touching only text1 and text3, text3 not touching text2. It has to touch that too. :(

Comment: Hi, I've updated the code, however I couldn't find the exact formula to calculate position of circle 3, what I made it's just an approximate solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure is what you want but here a modified example with circles touching each others:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <style>
      .circle-diagram {
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 190px;
      }
      .circle-diagram .solar-grid-wrapper {
        display: flex;
      }
      .circle-diagram .yellow-circle,
      .circle-diagram .yellow-circle-shadow {
        border-radius: 50%;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 12px;
        width: 130px;
        height: 130px;
        background-color: #feda02;
      }
      .circle-diagram .green-circle,
      .circle-diagram .green-circle-shadow {
        border-radius: 50%;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 12px;
        width: 91.05px;
        height: 91.05px;
        background-color: #25dc8a;
        left: 124px;
        top: 15px;
      }
      .circle-diagram .blue-circle,
      .circle-diagram .blue-circle-shadow {
        border-radius: 50%;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 12px;
        width: 119.8px;
        height: 119.8px;
        background: #3d7ff9;
        left: 108px;
        top: 106px;
      }
      .circle-diagram .symbol {
        height: 15px;
        margin-bottom: 8px;
      }
      .circle-diagram .value {
        z-index: 10;
        opacity: 1;
        font-weight: 550;
      }

      #randomButton {
        margin-top: 60px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        background: #3d7ff9;
        padding: 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="circle-diagram">
      <div class="solar-grid-wrapper">
        <div
          class="yellow-circle"
          id="circle1"
          style="width: 150px; height: 150px"
        >
          <div class="value">Cool text 1</div>
        </div>
        <div
          class="blue-circle"
          id="circle2"
          style="width: 160px; height: 160px;margin-left: -10px"
        >
          <div class="value">Cool text 2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div
        class="green-circle"
        id="circle3"
        style="width: 222px; height: 222px;margin-top: -30px"
      >
        <div class="value">Cool text 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button id="randomButton">Random Width</button>
  </body>
  <script>
    document.getElementById("randomButton").addEventListener(
      "click",
      function() {
        function random(min, max) {
          return Math.round(Math.random() * Math.abs(max - min) + min);
        }
        const randomNumber1 = random(150, 220);
        const randomMargin2 = random(10, randomNumber1 / 4);
        const randomNumber2 = random(150, 220);
        const randomNumber3 = random(150, 220);
        const randomMargin3 = random(10, randomNumber2 / 4);
        document.getElementById("circle1").style.width = `${randomNumber1}px`;
        document.getElementById("circle1").style.height = `${randomNumber1}px`;
        document.getElementById("circle2").style.width = `${randomNumber2}px`;
        document.getElementById("circle2").style.height = `${randomNumber2}px`;
        document.getElementById("circle2").style.marginLeft = `-${randomMargin2 }px`;
        document.getElementById("circle3").style.width = `${randomNumber3}px`;
        document.getElementById("circle3").style.height = `${randomNumber3}px`;
        document.getElementById("circle3").style.marginTop = `-${randomMargin3 }px`;
      },
      false
    );
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out but if you see the image, the edge should touch each other not getting inside.
Also if you click on the random width button, your example doesn't work. :(